# System.Web.Caching.Cache expires due to low memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, caching

I've been troubleshooting an issue that I am pretty sure relates to Cache on IIS server.  Item data randomly removed from our IIS worker cache.  The items that are removed have key value which made up using user's unique ID to ensure the cache key is unique.

Our application which runs on .NET 4.7.2 uses a lot of cache insert via the method [Insert(String, Object, CacheDependency)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.caching.cache.insert?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Caching_Cache_Insert_System_String_System_Object_System_Web_Caching_CacheDependency_) from System.Web.Caching.Cache

According to Microsoft doc, this method signature inserts the cache with no expire time unless the application pool is restarted or it suffers memory starves.

I look through the OS event viewer logs and I don't see any [event ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc735206(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) which indicates my application pool recycles because it reaches the private bytes memory limit.

We schedule to recycle our application pool daily during week day at 4am;  you see it from the memory graph below, however most of the time our issue of item lost from cache occurred during the day time.

[image]

My next steps to troubleshoot is adding more memory to the server, I wonder if IIS w3wp.exe suffers memory starve even though we still have some free memory on the server?

Is there anything you can potential see that could affect our cache item lifespan?

Comment: "w3svc.exe"? Are you sure?

Comment: @LexLi my bad, I edit the question, i mean w3wp.exe

Comment: Could you get it fixed by set priority to not removable? Since its uncertain the logic that server consider low memory, we may need to find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking the logeventonrecyle setting to see that recycling of the application pool is being logged. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/

It may be that other processes on the machine are using memory and you are loosing items due to "or it suffers memory starves"

To test this you could do a load test, where at the same time you start other processes on the server that use up the memory